# How to set image to UIButton by using RxCocoa

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimage, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm very new to RxSwift and RxCocoa. I want to set image to UIButton by using RxCocoa.

```
 settingButton.rx.image(for: .normal).onNext(UIImage.init(named: "closeButton"))
```

Any one have idea how to set image to UIButton? Am i doing right?

Comment: What are you trying to observe?

Comment: Is it right what I'm doing?  I just want to set image to UIButton

Comment: you *can* do it reactively, but doing it imperatively is easier, right? I strongly suggest you to do it imperatively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend you to set a button's image reactively. If you don't have any special reasons for doing this, do it the normal (imperative) way:

```
settingButton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "closeButton"), for: .normal)
```

Here's how you do it reactively, no need for `asObserver` and stuff:

```
button.rx.image().onNext(UIImage.init(named: "closeButton"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
viewModel.image
   .bind(to: button.rx.image(for: .normal))
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```